# Validating custom types which should only accept defined constant

Tags: json, validation, go

Here is the code that i have

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type PriorityLevel string

const (
    high   PriorityLevel = "P1"
    medium PriorityLevel = "P2"
)

type OrdersPriority struct {
    OrderID  string        `json:"order_id" validate:"required"`
    Priority PriorityLevel `json:"priority" validate:"required"`
}

var validate *validator.Validate

func main() {
    order := OrdersPriority{
        OrderID:  "Order_1",
        Priority: "random_priority",
    }

    validate = validator.New()
    err := validate.Struct(order)
    fmt.Printf("%+v", err)
}
```

As you can see that I have `PriorityLevel` which should have only `high` or `medium` values. How can i enforce this using `validator` ?

I know that in `validate` tag I can provide "possible" values but that option is not scalable i.e., if i end up adding more values to that constant, I would have to make that change there too. Is there more `Go` way to do so using this `validator` library?

Comment: You can define your custom validator for the field.

Comment: yup, thats one way to do it, is there any other way?

Answer (score 3):

You can use eq and put in multiple values but later on will be difficult to maintain

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    v "github.com/go-playground/validator/v10"
)

type Abc struct {
    A string `validate:"required,eq=public|eq=private"`
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
    a := Abc{
        A: "public",
    }
    b := Abc{
        A: "private",
    }
    c := Abc{
        A: "panda",
    }
    validator := v.New()
    err := validator.Struct(a)
    fmt.Printf("a %+v\n", err)
    err = validator.Struct(b)
    fmt.Printf("b %+v\n", err)
    err = validator.Struct(c)
    fmt.Printf("c %+v\n", err)
}
```

It will be better to use a custom validator function for your use case like

```
validate.RegisterValidation(`mycustomvalidator`, func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
    str := fl.Param()
    //Now you can check your custom validation here
    return str == "abc"
})
```

Comment: how is that different that using `oneof` ?

Comment: Using a custom function is better you can use a same constants across your code base easy to change in future; you can maybe create a slice of possible values and use everywhere

Comment: You can just check if you value lies in a slice of string in cuatom validator

Comment: @Em ae it is better than creating and updating tags everywhere